# Limit multiple print statements in query function

Tags: swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query records in DynamoDB. If the record is there, I want the console to print the market name and the customer's primary language. If the record is not there, I want the console to print "That info is not in our records."

However, at the moment, I have the `runQuery()` linked to a button where, when pressed, both statements print with one button press.

Note: The second statement prints four times.

Here is the function that runs when a button is pressed:

```swift
func runQuery(){
    
    appSyncClient?.fetch(query: ListCustomerRegistrationsQuery(),   cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataAndFetch) {(result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        result?.data?.listCustomerRegistrations?.items!.forEach {
            if $0?.firstInitial == self.firstInitialTextField.text && $0?.lastInitial == self.lastInitialTextField.text && $0?.needIndicatorId == self.numberNeedIndicatorTextField.text {
                print(($0?.marketName)! + " " + ($0?.primaryLanguage)!)

            }
            else if $0?.firstInitial != self.firstInitialTextField.text || $0?.lastInitial != self.lastInitialTextField.text || $0?.needIndicatorId != self.numberNeedIndicatorTextField.text {
                print("That info is not in our records.")
      
            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDistribution", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the print statements created after pressing that button once:

> "Downtown Market English"
>
> "That info is not in our records."
>
> "That info is not in our records."
>
> "That info is not in our records."
>
> "That info is not in our records."

Comment: So the response from the query contains 5 rows, I am not sure what the problem is here?

Comment: Yes, the response from the query contains 5 rows, instead of only returning one statement (depending on which one is appropriate), which is my goal. Seems like this implies an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you only want to return/print once when either of the `if` conditions are true. In that case I suggest you add a `break` in both places

```
result?.data?.listCustomerRegistrations?.items!.forEach {
    if $0?.firstInitial == self.firstInitialTextField.text && $0?.lastInitial == self.lastInitialTextField.text && $0?.needIndicatorId == self.numberNeedIndicatorTextField.text {
        print(($0?.marketName)! + " " + ($0?.primaryLanguage)!)
        return 
    }
    else if $0?.firstInitial != self.firstInitialTextField.text || $0?.lastInitial != self.lastInitialTextField.text || $0?.needIndicatorId != self.numberNeedIndicatorTextField.text {
        print("That info is not in our records.")
        return 
    }
}
```

Comment: Joakim, thanks for the reply. I am seeing this error when I try and insert the break: "Unlabeled 'break' is only allowed inside a loop or switch, a labeled break is required to exit an if or do"

Comment: @aaron228 Sorry that should have been `return`. I edit the answer

Comment: Joakim, I have updated my question to include the entire function because I am still having trouble getting out of the if statement with either one or the other print statements. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: @aaron228 Do you always want to do `self.performSegue(...)`? Maybe it's better to have it after the `forEach{}`block then. Other than that I don't understand what you mean when you say you have trouble getting out.

Comment: Joakim, The `runQuery()` is used by a button in my program, so I do need to do the `self.performSegue(...)` when the button is pressed. I moved it so it's after the `forEach{}` block and it seems to work the same as before. When I mentioned getting out, I was trying to convey that I'd prefer if the `runQuery()` returned one or the other of the print statements to the console before segueing.

Comment: @aaron228 And do you need two `if` conditions, could you replace the second one with just an `else {}` or since you have a return in the first if then no `else` at all and just the print?

Comment: Joakim, I removed the second ```else ``` condition and now it's working great. Thanks so much for the guidance.